# How to set UIScrollview height dynamically using programming

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've used `UIScrollview` in my `iPhone app`. I've set default size of `UIScrollview` `320 * 548`. I want to increase `UIScrollview` height dynamically using programming but i am not succeed yet. I've used below code

```
 CGRect scrollFrame;

scrollFrame.origin = _tblScroolView.frame.origin;

scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 700);

_tblScroolView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

Please help me

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to resize the scroll view or scrollable area?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I want to resize scroll view height. Thanks!

Comment: There is no iPhone screen higher then 568px, why would you set the height to 700?

Answer (score 10):

To change the size of scroll view

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, width, height);
```

to change the size of scrollable area:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

**Swift 3 version**

```
scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollX, y: scrollY, width:width, height:height)

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:width, height: height)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I have used both code but it didn't worked. In second code it is giving me below error 
"property contentview not found on object of type UIscrollview *; did you mean contentSize"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

trigger any function when you need to increase your scrollview then use this code in that function and make your desired size for scrollview

```
scrollViewName.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, width, height);
```

change scrollable area

```
scrollViewName.content.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int height = 600;
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
  // do what you want. suppose you create a view which size is - 10,10,300,800.

  height = createdView.frame.size.height+10;
}

scrollView.contentSize = (320, height);
```

Hope this will help you.